# Generalizing parsing of XML files from different Products

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am creating a web application. This application is for Order fulfillment for a E-commerce website. Right now E-commerce is IBM Websphere. I start by importing  the orders from Websphere by using its exposed webservice and parsing it and storing it into DB. Now they have requested to generalize this parsing thing so that tomorrow if they go with some other E-commerce product like prestashop also , it should cope up with. I need some ideas how to go about it and what all things i can keep as configurable options so that in future it wont create problems.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `Design Patterns`: One solution could be to use the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern):

You create a global, "generic" interface. Then you create an adapter for each E-commerce you need to support. For example, right now you would have one Adapter:

```
public class IBMImportAdapter : IECommerce
{
     private IBMECommerce _ibmInstance;

     public IBMImportAdapter(IBMECommerce instance) {
         _ibmInstance = instance;
     }

     public IEnumerable<Product> GetInput() {
         IEnumerable<IBMProduct> ibmProducts = _ibmInstance.TheirGetInput();
         List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
         foreach (IBMProduct p in ibmProducts) {
             products.Add(new Product(p.ID, p.Name);
         }
         return products;
     }
}
```

These adapters are then a mapping of their own interface to your global/generic interface. (in your case this might be pretty much the IBM E-commerce interface, but stripped of all IBM dependencies)

Another option would be to encapsulate the "importing algorithm" into a [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).